# pdflatex has stopped working

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex, texmaker

It has been a little while now that every time I try to compile a document with pdflatex I get an error message wich says "pdflatex.exe ha dejado de funcionar" (in English "pdflatex has stopped working").

This happened suddenly: before I had no problems for the compilation and now I try to compile the same documents and I get that error message.

Is there anything I could do to try to fix it?

If it is useful, my editor is Texmaker, I have MikTeX 2.9 and my OS is Windows Vista.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. check first on [commandline window](http://pcsupport.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=pcsupport&cdn=compute&tm=8&f=00&su=p284.13.342.ip_&tt=12&bt=5&bts=16&zu=http%3A//windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-Command-Prompt-window) `pdflatex -v` if its working. 2. Is this [hello.tex](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/hello.tex) example working ?. 3. if not as a last resort : Try resetting the TeXmaker settings : "Options" -> "Settings file" -> "reset settings" and Restart. And a new document must be saved with a `.tex` extension on Latest TeXmaker 4.0.2 version

Comment: I don't think pdflatex -v is working, it says that it is an unknown option. I reseted the Settings and it is still not working.

Comment: if `pdflatex -v` is not working . Did you restart PC after MiKTeX 2.9 install to take MiKTeX bin Path into effect ?. Make sure MiKTeX bin Path is added to windows Path by manually added. I cannot do more as I not on Windows now for more refer http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/.

Comment: How do I make sure that the bin path is added to windows path?

Comment: Type `path` at commandline window to see ...miktex\bin or else add bin to path. Normally MiKTeX would configure itself to windows path.

Comment: I think the path is working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9373/discussion-between-texenthusiast-and-anthea)

Comment: `pdflatex -v` doesn't work in miktex. In miktex you should use `pdflatex --version`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that doesn't seem reproducible (see chat discussion)